# Pandas slices row and adds it to the firts columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to display all the columns of a csv file. This is the file info.

[File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqqqe.png)

And this is the code I'm using:

```
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = None
pd.options.display.max_columns = None

excel1 = pd.read_csv('CO-Chats1.csv', sep=';')
```

But when I read it, I get this.

```
         Case Owner   Resolved Date/Time Case Origin  Case Number    Status  \
0   Reinaldo Franco  10/16/2021, 3:54 PM        Chat     20546561  Resolved   
1  Catalina Sanchez  10/16/2021, 5:38 AM        Chat      5625033  Resolved   

               Subject  
0      General Support  
1  Support for payment
```

Not sure what causes the \ and then adding the following columns to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `display()` instead of `print()` to see the output.

```
excel1 = pd.read_csv('CO-Chats1.csv', sep=';')
display(excel1)
```

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't help since it is not a "display" problem, but how pandas is formatting the information. Even when I use to_csv, this is what I get in the csv file:

Case Owner         Resolved Date/Time  Case Origin  Case Number Status     \

Comment: You could try to check whether excel1 is actually a Pandas DataFrame (`type(excel1)`) and then inspect `excel1.columns` to see which are actually the columns of the Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: This is what I get when checking type and columns:

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index(['Case Owner', ' Resolved Date/Time', 'Case Origin', 'Case Number',
       'Status', 'Subject'],
      dtype='object')